# Pivoting reasons into their own columns in R

Tags: r, pivot

I am working in R.

This is my data. Each school tells how many vacancies they have for each subject. They can give up to four reasons for why they think they have so many vacancies.

For example school 1 has given two reasons why English has so many vacancies (Pay and location).

```
data <- data.frame(school_id = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3"), 
                   subject = c("English", "English",  "Maths", "French", "French"),
                   vacancies = c(40, 40, 20, 40, 10),
                   Reason = c("Pay", "Location", "Pay", "Experience", "Location")
```

| school_id | subject | vacancies | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 40 | Pay |
| 1 | English | 40 | Location |
| 2 | Maths | 20 | Pay |
| 3 | French | 40 | Pay |
| 3 | English | 10 | Experience |

I want to pivot the reasons, so there is one row for every subject a school has reported vacancies for, but I can't seem to get it to work with pivot_longer or spread.

This is what I want....

| school_id | subject | vacancies | Reason1 | Reason2 | Reason3 | Reason4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 40 | Pay | Location | NA | NA |
| 2 | Maths | 20 | Pay | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | French | 40 | Pay | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | English | 10 | Experience | NA | NA | NA |

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
   mutate(rowid = row_number(), .by = c(school_id, subject)) %>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(school_id, subject, vacancies),
               names_from = rowid, 
               values_from = Reason,
               names_prefix = "Reason")

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  school_id subject vacancies Reason1    Reason2 
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   
1 1         English        40 Pay        Location
2 2         Maths          20 Pay        NA      
3 3         French         40 Experience NA      
4 3         French         10 NA         Location
```

Answer (score 2):

This matches OP's desired output and it's clear what is happening at each step.

First, we group the data by `school_id` and `subject` to identify which reason is first, which reason is second, etc. Then we pivot the table based on `school_id` and `subject`, using `Reason` as the value and `Reason_Name` as the column names.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(school_id, subject) %>% 
  mutate(Reason_Name = paste0("Reason", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(school_id, subject, vacancies),
    values_from = Reason,
    names_from = Reason_Name
  ) 

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  school_id subject vacancies Reason1    Reason2 
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   
1 1         English        40 Pay        Location
2 2         Maths          20 Pay        NA      
3 3         English        10 Experience NA      
4 3         French         40 Pay        NA
```

If we want to condense this code a bit, we can say:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    Reason_Name = paste0("Reason", row_number()), 
    .by = c(school_id, subject))
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(school_id, subject, vacancies),
    values_from = Reason,
    names_from = Reason_Name
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)

data |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = Reason,
                values_from = Reason,
                names_prefix = "Reason_") |>
    rename_with(.cols = starts_with("Reason_"),
                .fn =\(x) glue::glue("Reason_{1:3}"))

# A tibble: 4 × 6
  school_id subject vacancies Reason_1 Reason_2 Reason_3  
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     
1 1         English        40 Pay      Location NA        
2 2         Maths          20 Pay      NA       NA        
3 3         French         40 NA       NA       Experience
4 3         French         10 NA       Location NA
```

Comment: In your case you have the reasons as dummy. But that is not what op wants

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you described as your desired output but similar to GuedesBF's solution (we had a similar thought process it appears; I came up with it independently). But I think having a dataframe like this will be most useful:

```
require(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Reason, names_prefix = "Reason_", values_from = Reason) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = -c(school_id, subject, vacancies), .fns = \(x) !is.na(x)))

# output
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  school_id subject vacancies Reason_Pay Reason_Location Reason_Experience
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>           <lgl>            
1 1         English        40 TRUE       TRUE            FALSE            
2 2         Maths          20 TRUE       FALSE           FALSE            
3 3         French         40 FALSE      FALSE           TRUE             
4 3         French         10 FALSE      TRUE            FALSE
```

Comment: That is a good choice, having logical columns as the output. I believe you can do that with a single call to pivot_wider, though, looks cleaner than `pivot |> mutate(across)`: `data |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = Reason,
                values_from = Reason,
                values_fn = \(x) !is.na(x),
                values_fill = FALSE) `

Comment: Thanks all - super helpful answers and have solved my problem now.